# Web UI Test Automation

Tags: testing, user-interface, web-testing

I'm looking at the tools (Test Telerik WebUI Studio, Visual Studio 2010 Test Professional) to automate testing web applications written in NET. Do you use such tools? If so, what tools are you using and what experience do you have with this type of testing. Particularly I am interested in issues of maintenance of such tests (for example, if you change layouts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work for Telerik; I'm just sharing the relevant resources for the WebUI Test Studio*

Regarding the WebUI Test studio, there's a [free 30-day trial](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/download.aspx) that you can try yourself. There's a [weekly live demo](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/weekly-webinar.aspx), and you can even [request a free personal demo](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/demo-signup.aspx). Any of these might give you further insight whether the product will be suitable for your environment and might answer relevant questions.

Regarding the test-case maintenance, there is a [detailed feature overview on the product site](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/products/webui-test-studio-developer-edition/features/testcase-maintenance.aspx).

I hope this helps!

Comment: We decide to use Telerik WebAii Testing Framework with SpecFlow - and this is really great package.

Answer (score 0):

Go for CodedUI.It comes along with VSTS 2010 Ultimate.
The search criteria will continue to work even if you chnage the layout