# How to automate user interface testing in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, testing, automated-tests

Can anyone recommend a Visual Studio add-in or something else for automating testing with UI?

I want to test a web app written with web forms, something like macros, to put a sequence "run program, login with this account, go this page, click this button enter these values and if you get an error do something or if success do something"?

Any solution for this kind of problem would be helpful.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362588/web-ui-test-automation

Comment: I have used Selenium Web driver / RC / IDE to perform automated UI testing. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/. It has a Firefox plugin that you can use to record tests and export them as unit test. You can then run them with Selenium RC and play back your recorded actions.